# Magento how to get attribute value by option id?

Tags: php, magento

So I have

```
$attribute_option_id = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'my_attribute', $storeId);
```

This gives me something like `$attribute_option_id = 12345`

Now how do I get the (text) value for this id?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($productId);
$text = $product->getAttributeText('my_attribute');
```

**[EDIT]**
If you don't want to load the full product you can do a sneaky think. Impersonate a product.

So you get the option id like you already do

```
$attribute_option_id = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'my_attribute', $storeId);
```

Then create just an empty instance of the product and set some attributes to it.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->setData('my_attribute', $attribute_option_id);//the result from above

$text = $product->getAttributeText('my_attribute');
```

There is already a confirmation that this works. [See it here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/8396/146).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have to admit your answer works fine. But is there any method that'd get the $text from only the $attribute_option_id without loading the entire product data?

Comment: Nice. Wasn't expecting that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method that is a different approach that works for me.

Assume Known: $_current_productid

```
$_Current_OptionId =  Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($_current_productid, $attribute_id,$store_id);

$_write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

// now $_write is an instance of Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract

$_readresult=$_write->query("SELECT value FROM eav_attribute_option_value WHERE option_id ='".$_Current_OptionId."'"); 

while ($row = $_readresult->fetch() ) {$_Current_OptionValue=$row['value'];}
```

Comment: for getting admin option value it was only way I was able to retrieve it. Many thanks!!